# Is this video of someone dodging cars authentic?

Tags: video

I came across the below gif thanks to the [security.stackexchange.com chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27076581#27076581) and while this looks [more realistic than most "man dodges cars" viral videos](http://www.buzzfeed.com/rachelzarrell/this-viral-vine-of-a-guy-dodging-cars-is-both-insane-and-mos#.ts24YyXEP), I'm still skeptical.

[image]

Here is the accompanying [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZNa7xSGDeM) I found, and the car horns sounded super [stock](https://www.google.com/search?q=stock%20sounds), plus the fact I feel like some of those cars were far enough away to at least start braking.

Is this authentic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the question you (indirectly) refer to a [Vine video by Logan Paul](https://vine.co/v/O1AwluM75wd) which you acknowledge as fake.

The gif is derived from a Vine video by- you guessed it! -  [Logan Paul](https://vine.co/v/er3BDeABOTK) - it is the same stunt performer in both videos.

Granted, it is remotely possible that the first video was a fake and six months later the same person did the same skill live, but I hope you will agree that this is strong evidence the second video was produced using similar camera-trick techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but came across it randomly and thought I'd add a video explaining how this is done in video editing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63qn9w-a2ok

Comment: [Please do not put link-only answers on SE sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) Can you [edit] this and write the explanation *here* (leave the link for further reference, that's fine).